# redraw markers and clusters after location was inserted into collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

I have a map where my markers and clusters are rendered with leaflet. I have a collection where I have stored information like latitude/longtitude.

I iterate over the collection like this to insert the markers in

in Template.map.rendered

```
Locations.find({}).forEach(function(obj){
     console.log("Adding: lat " + obj.latitude + " - long " + obj.longtitude);
     var m = L.marker([obj.latitude,obj.longtitude]);
     markers.addLayer(m);
});
```

How can I also draw new inserted locations after the template was finished rendering that the map will be live updated?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as you do in your template. If you have a reference to the MarkerCluster layer (i'm assuming `markers`), just use the `addLayer` method of the layer:

```
markers.addLayer(L.Marker([0,0]);
```

If you want to bulk add markers you can use the method `addLayers`:

```
markers.addLayers([
    L.Marker([0,0]),
    L.Marker([1,1])
]);
```

MarkerCluster will take care of the rest, you can also animated the new inserts by using `animateAddingMarkers` in the options when instanciating the MarkerCluster:

```
new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    'animateAddingMarkers': true
});
```

> animateAddingMarkers: If set to true then adding individual markers to the MarkerClusterGroup after it has been added to the map will add the marker and animate it in to the cluster. Defaults to false as this gives better performance when bulk adding markers. addLayers does not support this, only addLayer with individual Markers.

Check the README.MD on their Github: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: ok but how to track the live updates(new locations)? via `Tracker.autorun`? When I load the screen and all markers/clusters are visible I can insert new `Locations` via console but they are not shown. just after a reload

Comment: Sorry to say Meteor is really out of my comfort zone, perhaps this will help you out, they seem to re-add the layer on each added marker: https://github.com/n0ne/meteor-markercluster/blob/master/client/views/map.coffee#L71 Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you load your Locations collection, via **collection.find()** or are you return a simple Locations array? The first option should be your prefered one since it is out of the box reactive.

Comment: just to clarify what I meant above: `collection.find().fetch()` is not reactive whereas `collection.find()` is a reactive cursor